# How to retrieve the value of the HTML <a> tag using Javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

How to retrieve the value of the HTML `<a>` tag using Vanilla Javascript

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a>Jill</a></td>
    <td><a>Sam</a></td>
    <td><a>10</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a>Eve</a></td>
    <td><a>Jeffreson</a></td>
    <td><a>55</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When the user clicks on the tag, I would like to retrieve the value of the tag so that I know which one was clicked on using JS

Here is what I tried: `var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function myFunction(val){
console.log(val.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a onclick="myFunction(this)">Jill</a></td>
    <td><a onclick="myFunction(this)">Sam</a></td>
    <td><a onclick="myFunction(this)">10</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a onclick="myFunction(this)">Eve</a></td>
    <td><a onclick="myFunction(this)">Jeffreson</a></td>
    <td><a onclick="myFunction(this)">55</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Do you know if there is a name to this particular technique?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a click event listener to the `<a>` elements, and then you can access the inner HTML of the element that triggered the event. Since you are retrieving a collection of HTML elements, you should iterate through it.

One way to iterate through a collection is to simply convert it to an array using `Array.from()` and then chain `.forEach()` to it:

```
const list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
Array.from(list).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  });
});
```

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  });
});
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Jill</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Sam</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">10</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Eve</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Jeffreson</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">55</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However I tend to recommend using `document.querySelectorAll` because you can pass CSS selectors as strings. Here is an example using `document.querySelectorAll()`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  });
});
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Jill</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Sam</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">10</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Eve</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Jeffreson</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">55</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the `list` using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and then just use `onclick` event and [`innerText` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) for each element:

```
Array.from(list).forEach(el => {
  el.onclick = function(e) {
    alert(this.innerText);
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

Array.from(list).forEach(el => {
  el.onclick = function(e) {
    alert(this.innerText);
  }
});
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a>Jill</a></td>
    <td><a>Sam</a></td>
    <td><a>10</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a>Eve</a></td>
    <td><a>Jeffreson</a></td>
    <td><a>55</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```